# How to recursively remove all adjacent duplicates

Tags: java, algorithm

I am not able to come up with a best solution ( O(n) time) to recursively remove adjacent duplicates from a string. My attempt :

```
public static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
   if ( s == null ) return null;
   if ( s.length() <= 1 ) return s;
   if( s.substring(1,2).equals(s.substring(0,1))) 
      return removeDuplicate(s.substring(1));
   else return s.substring(0,1) + removeDuplicate(s.substring(1));
}
```

But it does not work for cases such as :

```
 "azxxzy" -> "ay"
```

In above case these are the string transformations :

azxxzy
azzy
ay

Sample input outputs :

Input: azxxzy Output: ay

Input: caaabbbaacdddd Output: Empty String

Input: acaaabbbacdddd Output: acac

**UPDATE**

I have posted a version of answer below.

Comment: As long as you are working on a `String`, an O(n) solution will mean constant number of changes to it. Every "change" of a `String` in java is `O(n)`, because `String` is immutable..

Comment: remember about string concatenation complexity. using this data structure you won't make O(n) time

Comment: `System.out.println(removeDuplicate("azxxzy"));` with your code outputs `azxzy`. Looks fine...

Comment: @exception1 That's the problem, he wants it to be "ay".

Comment: @exception1 I think the intended output for that input is "ay".

Comment: ok, now I unserstand :) Sorry for that.

Comment: substring complexity depends on its implementation. in hotspot 6 it is constant time because it reuses the longer string.  in hotspot 7 it's off AFAIK so substring is O(result size)

Comment: @WarriorPrince There are a number of problems in your logic. However, the root problem is that you are not removing both of the duplicate characters from your String. The input "xxy" would return "xy" when it should return "y" (because your `equals` case only skips the first character, not the first 2). After you fix that, try it with input "xx" and you will see the next problem. As for complexity; see all other comments -- perhaps a linked list of characters, or a `char[]` where you replace characters to remove with 0 (e.g.) then rebuild the string afterwards with a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: no reason for downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this ugly solution with JasonC's idea (and actually my first idea which I did not pursue) of appending the characters to the output and in case there is adjacent duplicate deleting from the output.

```
public static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 char lastchar = '\0';
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   String str = builder.toString();
   if (!str.equals("")
       && (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == s.charAt(i))) {
     builder.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1);
   } else if (s.charAt(i) != lastchar)
     builder.append(s.charAt(i));
   lastchar = s.charAt(i);
 }
return builder.toString();
}
```

**UPDATE**
But the best solution is : with the help of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43578/31298)

```
public static String removeDuplicates(String s) {
if (s.isEmpty()) {
    return s;
}
char[] buf = s.toCharArray();
char lastchar = buf[0];

// i: index of input char
// o: index of output char
int o = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < buf.length; i++) {
    if (o > 0 && buf[i] == buf[o - 1]) {
        lastchar = buf[o - 1];
        while (o > 0 && buf[o - 1] == lastchar) {
            o--;
        }
    } else if (buf[i] == lastchar) {
        // Don't copy to output
    } else {
        buf[o++] = buf[i];
    }
}
return new String(buf, 0, o);
}
```

Comment: is ur solution o(n)?

Answer (score 4):

As people in the comments of your question have mentioned, `String` manipulations are already O(n) since `String` is immutable. This can be solved by using an array of `Character`s instead. Since you're also removing stuff, you should also use `null`s in that array in order to prevent having to move stuff around every time you remove characters. At the end you'll need to make an additional pass over the array to convert it into a string.

The real problem you are asking about is simpler. Removing `xx` from a string like `azxxzy` will put the characters before and after the `xx` next to each other, and they may be the same. So simply check for this again: Place the cursor one spot earlier. Continue with the string `zzy` rather than with `zy`.

The complexity would remain O(n), since every character is checked against at most twice and can be removed at most once.

Since you are asking specifically for a recursive answer, I'll assume this is a homework exercise and leave the implementation to you (use that `Character` array and add indices of the starting positions as extra argument to your method). A non-recursive algorithm would be more efficient as well as easier to implement!

Comment: How do you **remove** an element from an array in O(1)? remember you have to shift all elements to its right one step to the left - which is O(n). This will basically be the same O(n^2).

Comment: @amit Hence Ghostkeeper's suggestion to flag with `null` and do a second pass.

Comment: My strategy would be to replace it with `null` (you'd have to use `Character` rather than `char`), move the last character (the `z` before the pointer) to the right. Then at the end do an additional pass to remove the `null`s.

Comment: @JasonC It won't work, it will require repeatidly invoking the method - up to n/2 times. again, O(n^2).

Comment: @JasonC For example: "abc...yzzy....cba", in order to make sure the strings trims to null, you will have to repeat the process again and again, each iteration is O(n).

Comment: @WarriorPrince A linked list of characters would be another cumbersome but effective option to achieve your complexity requirements. Or you could take a completely different approach and build the output as you go (instead of removing from the input) with a `StringBuilder` (for example).

Comment: @amit No it wouldn't. The algorithm only removes the first consecutive characters of the substring it is examining; so: Set them to null, and skip ahead for next substring.

Comment: @amit In order to remove the nulls you only have to make *one* pass of "abc...yzzy...cba", which leaves the time linear. Ghostkeeper mentioned this as well. But Ghostkeeper also meant that that pass should be an iterative pass afterwards, and you seem to be imagining it as part of the recursion, so perhaps that explains the argument here? In any case, building the string into a `StringBuilder` on the way out of the recursion would be another option.

Comment: OK, I get what you meant now. Yea, it should work. However I am still unconftorable with the solution as the question explicitly asks for recursive approach (not that it will be hard to transform it to one).

Comment: @Ghostkeeper It is actually not a homework exercise. Else I would not have posted here or given O(n^2) solution which would have sufficed.

Comment: In that case, I'll see if I can make you a non-recursive solution and edit my post in a moment.

Comment: Honestly, a more accurate response would be to close as too-broad/opinion-based instead.

Comment: @JasonC: How is this too broad or opinion based? I would rather say its badly researched

Comment: @NiklasB. As evidence of "too broad/opinion based", see the answers it has tended to attract so far. Also the requirements are underspecified (as you encountered with your answer), and the nature of the logic errors in the original code mean that there is no clear, concrete answer -- only propositions for different possible approaches.

Comment: @Jason C: I guess that's the definition of "unclear what you're asking" or "lacking information to diagnose the problem"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple recursive python solution to remove all adjacent duplicates.

```
def rmv(st,i):
    if i==len(st)-1:
        return
    if not st:
        return 
    if st[i]==st[i+1]:
        tmp=st[i]
        while(i<len(st) and st[i]==tmp):
            st.pop(i)
        if not i-1:
            rmv(st,i-1)
        else:
            rmv(st,0)
    else:
        rmv(st,i+1)

inp=list("azxxzy")
rmv(inp,0)
print ''.join(inp)
```

This program prints **ay** as output.

Answer (score 0):

I converted it to a char array. Also I'm not sure how fast this is completed in, but your question didn't seem to stress about the O-time, you just wanted one that worked (if I read your question correctly).

Converting to a char array means you don't have to work with Strings, which are immutable (so you have to reconstruct them each time you make a change).

```
public static String removeDuplicate(String string) {
    if(string == null) return null;
    return String.copyValueOf(removeDuplicate(string.toCharArray()));
}

public static char[] removeDuplicate(char[] chars) {
    if(chars.length < 1) return new char[0];
    else if(chars.length == 1) return chars;

    for(int i=0; i<chars.length-1; i++) {
        if(chars[i] == chars[i+1]) {
            char[] before = Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, 0, i);
            char[] after = Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, i+2, chars.length);
            char[] combined = new char[before.length + after.length];
            System.arraycopy(before, 0, combined, 0, before.length);
            System.arraycopy(after, 0, combined, before.length, after.length);
            chars = removeDuplicate(combined);
            break;
        }
    }
    return chars;
}
```

You can test it with this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(removeDuplicate("azxxzy"));
    System.out.println(removeDuplicate("Does this have any duplicates?"));
    System.out.println(removeDuplicate("Nfggfoyy frttrfihht dfbllbfoedssssdsnpr''rp'tuiiu"));
}
```

Comment: For input : acaaabbbacdddd
Expected output : acac
Your Output is:  acabac

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **stack** for this :

```
 public class StackDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CharStackArray stack = new CharStackArray(15);
        char[] dupliactes = { 'a', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'y' };
        stack.removeAdjacentDuplicate(dupliactes);
    }

}

class CharStackArray {
    private char[] array;
    private int top;
    private int capacity;

    public void removeAdjacentDuplicate(char[] arr) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (isEmpty()) { // if stack is empty
                push(arr[i]);
                display();
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                int count = 0;
                int j = i;
                /*
                 * while top of stack is equal to next value in array (ie same
                 * adjacent values)
                 */
                while (j < arr.length && peek() == arr[j]) {
                    count++; // count of same occurences
                    j++;
                }
                if (count == 0) { // no same occurence
                    push(arr[i]); // push to stack
                    display();
                    System.out.println();
                } else {
                    for (int k = 1; k < count; k++) // skip the array index for
                        // same adjacent duplicates
                        i++;
                    pop(); // pop the duplicate value from stack
                    display();
                    System.out.println();

                }
            }

        }
    }

    public CharStackArray(int cap) {
        capacity = cap;
        array = new char[capacity];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push(char data) {
        array[++top] = data;
    }

    public char pop() throws Exception {
        return array[top--];
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + "->");
        }
    }

    public char peek() throws Exception {
        return array[top];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == -1);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

a->

a->z->

a->z->x->

a->z->

a->

a->y->

Answer (score 0):

A non recursive simple solution is

```
public class RemoveAdjucentDuplicates {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "azxxzy";
    s = "geeksforgeeg";
    System.out.println(remove(s));
}

static String remove(String s) {
    char res[] = new char[s.length()];
    int j = 0;
    res[j] = s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != res[j]) {
            res[++j] = s.charAt(i);
        } else {
            res[j--] = '\u0000';
        }
    }

    String result = String.valueOf(res);
    return result.substring(0,j+1);
}
}
```

Comment: How would you handle casese like : acccv

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RemoveAdjacant
{
 public String replaceAdjacent(String s)
 {
  if (s.equals(""))
   return s;
  String adjacentString = "";
  char cha;
  int count = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
   cha = s.charAt(i);
   adjacentString = adjacentString + cha;
   for (int j = 1 + i; j < s.length(); j++)
   {
    if (cha == s.charAt(j))
    {
     adjacentString = adjacentString + cha;
     count++;
    } else
    {
     if (count >= 3)
      break;
     else
     {
      count = 1;
      adjacentString = "";
      break;
     }
    }
   }
   if (count >= 3)
   {
    int index = s.indexOf(adjacentString);
    s = s.substring(0, index)
      + s.substring(index + adjacentString.length());
    return replaceAdjacent(s);
   }
  }
  return s;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  RemoveAdjacant ra = new RemoveAdjacant();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter string");
  String s = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("rem string=" + ra.replaceAdjacent(s));
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey BISHWAJEET, nice to see that someone cares about old questions! Would be even nicer if you could add some explanation or documentation for the code

Comment: Hey, Here the output is coming when any character is adjacent >=3 times then removing that whole adjacent character substring and then again applying same logic in remaining String.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, It is better to use recursion . Moreover conversion of string to character array also consumes some time. So, I would prefer to go with normal string input.

My code would somehow look like following( I have used Java 8):

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

    /*
     "Given a string, remove the consecutive character pairs repetitively.
    input: saabbs , output : 
    input: aaabbbccc , output : abc"

     */

    class Solution {
      public static String removeDuplicates(String s) {
        int count=0;
        String sout = "";
        if (s.isEmpty() || s.length()==1) {
            return s;
        }
        else{
          s=s+" ";
          for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)!= s.charAt(i+1) || s.charAt(i+1)==' '){
              sout = sout+s.charAt(i);
            }else{
              count++;
              i=i+1;
            }
          }
        }
        //int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<sout.length()-1;i++){
          if(sout.charAt(i)==sout.charAt(i+1))
            count++;
        }
        if(count>0){
          return removeDuplicates(sout);
        }else
          return sout;
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
       // String s = "saabbs";
      String s1 = "aaabbbccc";
      //System.out.println("Output1:\t"+removeDuplicates(s));
      System.out.println("Output2:\t"+removeDuplicates(s1));
        timer.stop();
         System.out.printf("Time taken: %,10d microseconds\n", timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS));

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package algorithms;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Sample().fix("Whaaaatupducck");
    }

    public void fix(String input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int index = 0; index<input.length()-1 ;index++){

            System.out.println("compare "+ 
            input.charAt(index)+                
            " and "+
            input.charAt(index+1));

            if(input.charAt(index) == input.charAt(index+1)){
                continue; // skipping repeats
            }else{
                sb.append(input.charAt(index));
            }

            if((index+2) == input.length()){
                sb.append(input.charAt(index+1)); // handling last character
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result : "+sb.toString());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> compare W and h| compare h and a| compare a and a| compare a and a|
>   compare a and a| compare a and t| compare t and u| compare u and p|
>   compare p and d| compare d and u| compare u and c| compare c and c|
>   compare c and k|

Result :

> Whatupduck

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using stack :

```
private static String remove(String str1) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    stack.push(str1.charAt(0));
    int inx = 1;
    char lastDeleted = '\0';
    while(!stack.isEmpty() && inx < str1.length()){
        if(str1.charAt(inx) == stack.peek()) {
            //repeating character found..
            lastDeleted = stack.pop();
        }else if(str1.charAt(inx) == lastDeleted) {
            //repeating character found but already removed from the stack.
        }else {
            //when a new character is introduced..
            stack.push(str1.charAt(inx));
        }
        inx++;
        if(stack.isEmpty() && inx < str1.length()) {
            //if stack is empty, then insert at least one element if present..
            stack.push(str1.charAt(inx));
            inx++;
        }
    }
    if(stack.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }else {
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            sb.insert(0, stack.pop());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class RemoveAdjacentDuplicates {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(removeDuplicates("azxxzy"));
        }

         public static String removeDuplicates(String S) {
             char[] stack = new char[S.length()];

             int i = 0;

             for(int j = 0 ; j < S.length() ; j++) {

                 char currentChar = S.charAt(j);
                 if(i > 0 && stack[i-1] == currentChar) {
                     i--;
                 }else {
                     stack[i] = currentChar;
                     i++;
                 }

             }
             return new String(stack , 0 , i);
         }

    }
```

Result of the program is :

```
    input - "azxxzy" 
    output - "ay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void removeDuplicates(String str)
     {
         if(str.length()<=1)
         {
             System.out.println(str);
             return;
         }
         String n=new String();
         int count=0;
         for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
         {
             while(i<str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
             {
                 if(i<str.length()-2 && str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(i+2))
                    i+=2;
                 else
                    i++;
                 count++;
             }
             if(i!=str.length()-1){
                 n=n+str.charAt(i);
             }
             else if(i==str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(i-1)){
                 n=n+str.charAt(i);
             }
         }
         if(count>0)
         removeDuplicates(n);
         else
         System.out.println(n);
     }
}
```

Result:

```
Input: acaaabbbacdddd
Output : acac
Input : azxxzy
Output: ay
```